# Error de encontrar directorio con shutil y lista comprehension

Tags: python, lista, script

antes de nada gracias por darme respuestas, soy nuevo en python.

Estoy creando un script en python ya que otro programa me da unos ficheros separados por comas tal que así:

```
_V6A9103,_V6A9143,_V6A9154,_V6A9197,_V6A9201,_V6A9223,_V6A9239,_V6A9260,_V6A9267,_V6A9298
```

Bueno pues lo que quiero es encontrar estos archivos en grandes cantidades (como 200 de estos archivos) en una carpeta que tiene mas archivos que no quiero (alrededor de 1500). En un hilo anterior aclaré alguna de mis dudas y he hecho este código:

```
import shutil
import os



file_source = "/Users/irenelopez/Downloads/prueba/"
file_destination = '/Users/irenelopez/Programación/prueba/'


archivos = input("Escribe tus archivos: ")
archivos2 = archivos.replace(",", '.JPG,')
print(archivos2)

archivos3 = [a for a in archivos2.split(',') if a != '']
print(archivos3)
 
for g in archivos3:
    shutil.move(file_source + g, file_destination)
```

Bueno pues esto en teoría debería reemplazar las comas de la cadena de antes por ".JPG,". Esto para poner un formato de archivo. Después pongo las comillas en cada uno de los archivos y ya se copian, pero me sale este error, como si estuviera buscando los archivos con una comilla de mas, alguien me puede ayudar? gracias.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 

'/Users/irenelopez/Downloads/prueba/_V6A9103.JPG' -> '/Users/irenelopez/Programación/prueba/_V6A9103.JPG'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/irenelopez/Programación/dobletemp.py", line 16, in <module>
    shutil.move(file_source + g, file_destination)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 835, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 434, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 254, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/irenelopez/Downloads/prueba/_V6A9103.JPG'
```

Comment: Lista el directorio y revisa que el archivo existe con las mismas mayúsculas/minúsculas.

Comment: No veo eso que dices de una comilla de más. El error está diciendo simpemente que el archivo `/Users/irenelopez/Downloads/prueba/_V6A9103.JPG` no existe. ¿Puedes verificar que realmente exista? Por otro lado, tu truco de reemplazar las comas por JPG no funcionará para el último archivo, pues ese no lleva coma al final

Comment: a mi me psaba que a veces no reconocia el directorio porque al trabajar en windows tenia que usar doble // y no / o incluso con barras invertidas \\ podrias intentar eso, tambien verifica que el directorio desde donde comienza la busqueda este correcto ya que muchas veces no inicia desde tu ruta de ejecucion.